# Restore contacts from VCF to SIM Card

Tags: contacts, sim-card

I've been trying to restore contacts from a vCard backup I have (VCF file) to the SIM card.

So far I managed to do it, but only through an app called "Simple contacts - Easy contact manager" (https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.simplemanage.contactsapp&hl=en_US&gl=US). From there, I can click Import from VCF file and it will have the option to select the SIM card "account". When I try from the Contacts app, no such "account" appears, and I can only select PHONE or Google Account. So I think the app enables the option from the Contacts app, which might be locked because of any non-sense reason (unless it's because of what I'll say in a bit, and if it is, I'd like to know why they didn't fix it...). When I try to do this, all contacts are restored perfectly with absolutely no errors. Though, after a restart, all are gone from the SIM card. No trace. No explanation also...

From another idea, I've also not found another app that imports from VCF to the SIM card directly, so I restored to the phone (perfect restoration) and copied to the SIM card. This ended up in one of 2 ways only: either the names would be incomplete many when there are special characters on them (it would cut them for some reaason), or it would still cut the names, but less times and only with one app which I don't remember anymore because I've been trying various (if needed I can look for it).

In some cases, they will be shown perfectly on the app that copied them, but when I open the Contacts app, their names will be cut.

Since it seems to have to do with special characters, I've thought in being related with encodings (the encoding used on the phone memory). A wrong encoding could be taking too much space for the SIM card to store or something, but no idea, just came to my mind.

Does anyone know a decent way of restoring the contacts to the SIM card...? I don't want to be forced to go get my Nokia Navigator or another one even older I have from 2008 (the Navigator at least I know it can do this because I used to do it, the other one I'm not sure) to do something an Android phone (much more recent and more powerful) can't and should be able to do, every time from now on.

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: That's the problem with using  SIM card, names are truncated because of length restrictions, only name & number pairs can be stored, no other details, you can't store more than 250 contacts // Using SIM card for contacts means you have to live with these restrictions

Comment: Yeah, but I don't mind at all. The thing is I can write the contacts there myself manually one by one and they'll remain saved. If I copy from phone to SIM, they're either get truncated for some reason, or they'll be saved perfectly and last until a reboot. I just don't want to write them myself again or go get a Nokia to do it right because an Android phone can't! Makes no sense to me why I can't copy contacts to SIM decently but I can write them myself manually like I did for 20 minutes with 140 contacts... But I'd like not to do it myself --> vCard - and the phone doesn't cooperate... Cool.